# Получить значение заголовка "Location"

Tags: redirect, javascript

Делаю запрос к странице сайта, при этом в ответе происходит редирект совершенно на другой сайт. Вот мне нужна часть того нового url. Был приятно удивлён, что в спеках XMLHttpRequest нет ни слова про выключение авторедиректа. Тем не менее может проблема всё же решается?

Comment: А что мешает регекспами вытащить новый урл(или его часть) ?

Comment: откуда вытаскивать?

Answer (score 1):

```
getAllResponseHeaders()
```

Наверно это должно помочь увидеть все заголовки.

Comment: Должно, если бы XMLHttpRequest не редиректил без спроса.